# Trying to understand how my python code works

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, arraylist

```
i = [1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14, 14,]

list_length = len(i)

def numbers_found(x):
    y = i.count(x)
    return y
    


latest_num = i[list_length - 1]

for z in range(latest_num + 1):
    print("Found", numbers_found(z), "of number", "\"" + str(z) + "\".")
```

I am trying to find how many of a certain number is available in the list, if I somehow minus by 1 to the maximum number in the list (assuming it is in ascending order) and add 1 again it works. Please help explain this to me.

Comment: Because indexing is [*zero*-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering).

Comment: Yes, but how does it work if the length of the array is 9, but subtracting by 1 gives the numbers found until 13, and then adding 1, gives it till 14, however just typing 13 in the "range(13)" gives a list out of range error.

Comment: The length of your array is 10. Indexing is zero-based tho, so the index of the last element is 9. So subtracting 1 from the length works to get the last element (which btw could be more easily done by using `i[-1]`). I don't see `13` anywhere in your code, and `range(13)` gives an error bc the maximum value produced by that range is 12, which is still out of range for indexing the list.

Comment: But see that is what I am trying to understand, how does the code work if the range I have put in "range(latest_num + 1)" is larger than 10. Understand what I am trying to figure out here?

Comment: Yeah, that's because `range` is exclusive for it's upperbound. In other words, `range(10)` goes from 0 to 9, but excludes `10`.

Comment: the 13 was an example, sorry I didn't mean it was in my code, I could even mean range(15), because maximum number is 14, but if I write that instead, error would be given as you already know, index is out of range. But also look, list_length is the length of the amount of numbers available in the list, which is 9, now if we find the last number, assuming that it is always the largest, and then we assign i[list_length - 1] to latest_num, then at range(latest_num + 1) we get that range(latest_num + 1) can also mean 14, as the last number in the list is 14, we subtracted it by 1 and added back 1.

Comment: No problem. But Eletrix, it seems like your confusion about how indexing and `range` work is pretty deep. I would like to keep helping you, but per Stack Overflow's commenting polices, the comment section is really only intended for clarification from the author, not extended question answering.

Comment: But no worries, you have a couple of options. First, you can pop-over to the [Python groupchat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) and try to get some help, or you hop over to another online forum dedicated to debugging code. One of my favorites is [the r/codinghelp subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/CodingHelp/). Happy coding!

Comment: yep, I understood now, I thought that typing range(15) gave an error, I tried again, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets break it down, step by step.

```
# a list. indexes shown below
#    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8   9
i = [1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14, 14]

# getting the length of the list (10)
# or the number of elements
list_length = len(i)

# a function returning the amounts of
# times a passed value is found in the list i
def numbers_found(x):
    y = i.count(x)
    return y

# see above that list_length is 10
# but we need one less that to retrieve the last element
# which will be 14
latest_num = i[list_length - 1]

# range given 1 argument iterates from 0
# to the number you pass it but not including it
# since latest_num is 14, it won't include it
# So range(15) would iterate like
# 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
for z in range(latest_num + 1):
    print("Found", numbers_found(z), "of number", "\"" + str(z) + "\".")
```

The reason `range` works like this, is it's common to see `range(length_of_my_list)` and expect it to return indexes for the full list.
In order for that to happen you need to only iterate to and not include the length. In your case (`10`).

What you are using it for is something else. You are trying to find the occurrences of all the numbers in the `list`. Since you are not using it for indexes, adding `+ 1` works since you WANT it to include `14`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
for z in range(len(i)):
     print("Found", numbers_found(z), "of number", "\"" + str(z) + "\".")
```

Here len(i) is the size of i i.e. the number of elements in i, and range(n) = [0, 1, ..., n - 1] i.e all numbers from 0 to n-1, sorted asc.

Comment: Hi Daniel111, thanks for the answer, but this doesn't explain though the core problem with OP's code, namely that indexing is zero-based. This code works because `range` is exclusive with it's upper bound.

Comment: That won't fix the problem, originally I had this, but if the length of the array is 9, and I have the number until say 15, this will only output numbers from 0-9, instead of outputting until the maximum number available in the list.